# Get the type of which a key is a keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I try to determine the type of which a given key is a keyof without explicitly typing the generics:

```
type TypeOne = {a:string, b:string}
type TypeTwo = {c:string, d:string}

function doSomething<T extends TypeOne | TypeTwo>(firstKey: keyof T, secondKey: keyof T) {
    console.log(firstKey, secondKey)
}

doSomething<TypeOne>('a','c')

doSomething('a','c')
```

When typing the doSomething call (first call), it works as expected (meaning: typescript complains).

But as far as I can see, Typescript could be so smart to determine which type a key actually belongs to, such that the doSomething without type binding (second call) could work as well (meaning, it should throw a warning for the second parameter only).

See [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkB20C8UDeBDAXAZ2ACcBLJAcwBooAjfI0sgXwChRJZ4YB3AeynQwBjOiXJUAJiIYtmAMwCuSQcGI8kUcTwDKPALYRgACwYAeGFAgAPYBCTi8HSMmgAfRxG48AfAApZxQgIAaQgQHCgAa1CeWVgqPAhBNXEQsMjo2JgASkxmKHyoJKQ8HgAbCAA6Up4yPwDg0IoEopTQrOYZTR19I1M4JxRfAHIsIYohwSH25i69A2NyHxGxianmIA)

I tried something like:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

function doSomething<T extends TypeOne | TypeTwo>(firstKey: KeysOfUnion<T>, secondKey: KeysOfUnion<T>) {
    console.log(firstKey, secondKey)
}
```

But that doesn't help either, since all keys together seems to be 'unioned' to create all possible options for the parameters.

Addition, as a response of the answer of Tamas Hegedus

My union comes from an ever expanding type like below:

```
type AllOptions = {
    one: TypeOne,
    two: TypeTwo
}

function doSomething<T extends AllOptions[keyof AllOptions]>(firstKey: KeysOfUnion<T>, secondKey: KeysOfUnion<T>) {
    console.log(firstKey, secondKey)
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Naplnw) meet your needs?  It should scale with the union automatically.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It also does, I can create this utilityType easily with all union options. Thanks!

Comment: By "also" do you mean the other answer is acceptable to you? I'm not inclined to write up an answer if there's already one you're happy with.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz no please share, I think it is an easier solution, with only the drawback that the rest operator doesn't look so nice in the parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to clarify union types.

```
function doSomething<T extends TypeOne | TypeTwo>(...
```

It does not mean that `T` is either `TypeOne` or `TypeTwo`. There are types that extend both, and those might even have extra fields, for example:

```
doSomething<{
    a: string, b: string,
    c: string, d: string,
    xy: string,
}>('a', 'xy'); // No type errors, it accepts 'xy'!
```

To achieve either-or semantics, I suggest using [TypeScript Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), like this:

```
type TypeOne = { a: string, b: string };
type TypeTwo = { c: string, d: string };

function doSomething2(firstKey: keyof TypeOne, secondKey: keyof TypeOne): void;
function doSomething2(firstKey: keyof TypeTwo, secondKey: keyof TypeTwo): void;
function doSomething2(firstKey: string, secondKey: string): void {
    console.log(firstKey,secondKey);
}

doSomething2('a', 'b'); // OK
doSomething2('c', 'd'); // OK
doSomething2('a', 'c'); // NOT OK
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkB20C8UDeUCGAuKAzsAE4CWSA5gDRQBG+RZlUAvgNwBQoks8MA7gHso6LAGMGJctSgATSUwqtOHAGYBXJGOClBSOYIDKggLYRgAC2kAmABSrSxIgGkIIfAGs3g1b0jIIGgIIMT1ZV3coLxAfP0QUAEp8ADdBUllODS0dPQNjM0sbe0cXN09vXzhIAUEgkLCI8pjKviEkqFT0zM1tXX1ZI1NzK0o7BydgRsIpSjrQpHCy6cV2ztlMDigtqHmCQQAbCAA6fcEKYomIqmD5xZAEzhYODgH84aKAcmwPmg-aD4eUAA9ECoAhnC9BgURhQ7B8xD8oB9ZAC2MDQeDIW9CqNbF9EfDUeioAA5BAwMEQtQ9HL9KHvSgARgAPBSIAAPYAQBYEOIBKAAHziNQAfBdSpForEYHMGkspZUEhttjs9HtDiczuLJm5ZQsIg8OE8sUMcRQWVV4hAxfjfgjDa9TTCWVg8MtpDR6O7ZjsFB65H6fezIoxpKwbd9fsHUSbodJGXjI0j7ZwgA)

**Update**: In your use case, hardcoding the set of types in overloads is not feasible. There might still be a way, but you wouldn't get nice error messages and we are roaming on a territory where typescript doesn't really know what's going on anymore, so don't expect typescript to do any inference down the line.

```
type Types = {
  v1: { a: string, b: string },
  v2: { c: string, d: string },
};
type FilterKeys<T> = Values<{ 
  [U in keyof Types]: (
    IsSubset<T, keyof Types[U]> extends true ? keyof Types[U] : never
  )
}>;


function doSomething1<const T>(firstKey: T & FilterKeys<T>, secondKey: T & FilterKeys<T>) {
  console.log(firstKey, secondKey);
}

doSomething1('a', 'b'); // OK
doSomething1('c', 'd'); // OK
doSomething1('a', 'c'); // NOT OK, error on first arg
doSomething1('a', 'u'); // NOT OK, error on first arg
doSomething1('u', 'v'); // NOT OK, error on first arg
doSomething1<'a' | 'x'>('a', 'x'); // NOT OK, error on first arg


// Second version is a tad bit more sophisticated, it will highlight the first arg that does not match
function doSomething2<
  const T1 extends FilterKeys<never>,
  const T2 extends FilterKeys<T1>
>(firstKey: T1, secondKey: T2) {
  console.log(firstKey, secondKey);
}

doSomething2('a', 'b'); // OK
doSomething2('c', 'd'); // OK
doSomething2('a', 'c'); // NOT OK, error on second arg
doSomething2('a', 'u'); // NOT OK, error on second arg
doSomething2('u', 'v'); // NOT OK, error on first arg
doSomething2<'a', 'c'>('a', 'c'); // NOT OK, error on second type parameter


type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type IsSubset<Q, S> = Q extends S ? true : false;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oG8BQUoDcCMAXOlAIZELABOAlgHYDmANFAEblV31QC%20jWuAJiJooAY3Y0GzACYTOPPtwDcGUJCgAxagBtgESgGkIIBAB4YAPhRQAaiW0BXRKZH8A2gFUodKAGtjAPYAZrDwCAC6RAAU-NgAkggAyg4sCBDA5sz%20IMGhkAie4VYQAB56tNJIVE5QAPx%20gSFw%20YVQRLQQOPr8AJQY3BYqGBhBDrSiwNQBtFDSAYkBALbpABaceKai0xSwFlFB1JQURiBEMFAAZJo6eobGZpbMaVsVJ2eX17r6Jw8WPej8F4IALaCAAOm0AXo%200Ox2MTwgL2kJx6Km4wzmC2WwDWDDwUQA5CQCcwCSwCaioAB6KlQADyBgwmKWq3WhNEJKgBOkFKU1NpDKZ8xZOLZRM5BI5lJpUAAcnTzgzmPpKAFKFBplADkdgKRKPQhVjWXjCcTSQ5efy5Qr6QZlZRVerNdqdiR9YaRbj6PiCRbSThLTL5Yq7VAVWqNTMXbq3QbmdivRtxVAAD5ckoEvbi0kZ6W04O2%202OyNa2Ex93DGWJRHTaS4fQIKYzahIEhQYAkOssai6xZq6DAsBrCjUUQkPTSZg9qAAdx02iga3oK201GXupx0Gjeq4OPHswCiCgtACvfHohWIzGEybB6NooYAlMgO2upgeDDZQgFSQWi%20dxMUwOi6SgLD4bAgTfARP3KSpPluH5zDwCwMD2aM3lgPAESRDCYAEf5MAg7YQXBSFoXQ%20EoGeWsUTRDFhQTTgBFNCVyTzW0PUYx92QlHl2MFeNjXoZjsy5KU%20SDG0lTDB0I01aiKh3TihJEs0uQtdiC2k8MnRmBS61jZSH2Ewk-S5ANNKk0MdJLbdDME4yn1EyVMxY0lxKtLTrNk3SqJrRS1GgMA3RIbFumGQLbHsJxfmsGA3GyXIYHCFRIoSZJUnSUwAEVmESKxUGymDvzgxI6nbSgaiIIJ7DSFQgA)

**Update**: Turns out there is a way to programmatically generate overloads. The code is not too long, not too complicated, and you get all the benefits hardcoded overloads would provide.

```
type Types = {
  v1: { a: string, b: string },
  v2: { c: string, d: string },
}

type IntersectObjectValues<T> = { [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => void }[keyof T] extends (x: infer X) => any ? X : never;

type GenerateOverloads<T> = IntersectObjectValues<{ [K in keyof T]: (x: keyof T[K], y: keyof T[K]) => void }>;

const doSomething: GenerateOverloads<Types> = (x, y) => {
  console.log(x, y);
};

doSomething('a', 'b'); // OK
doSomething('c', 'd'); // OK
doSomething('a', 'c'); // NOT OK, no overload matches this call
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEGcoF4oG8BQUoDcCMAXOlAIZELABOAlgHYDmANFAEblV31QC%20jWuAJiJooAY3Y0GzACYTOPPtwwZQkKAElawCJQQRRwAPIsAVvuAA1EgBsArogA8MAHwpiAbQDSUOlADWECAA9gBmsAC6RAAUAB5EMF7hAJQorjhB1NI87gHBYTDhUBAx2rTSSLFEdCE6UAAaKciuJLQgUAD89VBEtBA4OgDcyqrQAOIQvZQk2ob9lNZBJOVOrqia2rrmxmYGVnaOIl4%20tP6BoRHRcad5sInMIES55wmeyam4GVnczkMYokG0ChQaRBADKQQAthBgAALThEcaTaYQWY6BZLBBOeAIVZQWL3RquTDYf6AoLWCAAOgW9HxUBASSG3F%20IPBUNhnCiAHISFzmFyWFzGVAAPQiqCGTwYVmQ6Fwhjc0R8qBc6RCgai8WS6Vg2UchU85VcpXCsVQAByhhgEs8zFoQSgQTm6KyEOmohhiCgHKQohs1mUQA)

Comment: The reason to come up with 'KeysOfUnion' were because of your explanation about unions. But it was the best I could come up with. 
Your solution works, thanks, but my union type actually comes from an ever expanding type 'AllOptions' of which the values become the actual union. 
I would have to overload the function with every addition to the union. I would like to prevent that.

Comment: I see. I don't have a solution for that right off the bat, and I am afraid it might be impossible to do so. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Michiel I have an update for you

Comment: Cool! That is really a neat solution. Although my colleagues checking my pull requests will say it is way too complicated :-D
But definitely you answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: And I would agree with your colleagues :) Check this out, there is an even better solution, although it might still be too much magic for most teams

Comment: Nice! I will use one of the solutions and see what they'll say about it. Thanks for helping me out, Typescript still has a lot of secrets for me, but now a little less.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually you want to support multiple distinct call signatures, like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  But because the different conceptual call signatures all have the same return type (`void`), you can represent them as a *single* non-[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature, whose [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of appropriately shaped [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).  That is, you want the argument list to either be of type `[keyof TypeOne, keyof TypeOne]` *or* of type `[keyof TypeTwo, keyof TypeTwo]`.

You can get the compiler to compute this from the `TypeOne | TypeTwo` union via a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type KeysPairFromUnion<T> =
    T extends unknown ? [firstKey: keyof T, secondKey: keyof T] : never;

type TypeOne = { a: string, b: string }
type TypeTwo = { c: string, d: string }

type DoSomethingArgs = KeysPairFromUnion<TypeOne | TypeTwo>;
/* type DoSomethingArgs = 
     [firstKey: keyof TypeOne, secondKey: keyof TypeOne] | 
     [firstKey: keyof TypeTwo, secondKey: keyof TypeTwo] 
*/
```

And then `doSomething()` can be implemented with a single call signature like this:

```
function doSomething(...[firstKey, secondKey]: KeysPairFromUnion<TypeOne | TypeTwo>) {
    console.log(firstKey, secondKey)
}
```

Note the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into the `firstKey` and `secondKey` local variables, so the implementation will work as before with no change.

---

Let's make sure it works as desired from the caller's side:

```
doSomething('a', 'b'); // okay
doSomething('c', 'd'); // okay
doSomething('a', 'a'); // okay
doSomething('a', 'c'); // error
```

Looks good.  Notice that while you're calling it, IntelliSense will present the function as if it were an overloaded function with multiple call signatures:

```
doSomething(
//          ^ 1/2 doSomething(firstKey: keyof TypeOne, secondKey: keyof TypeOne): void
//            2/2 doSomething(firstKey: keyof TypeTwo, secondKey: keyof TypeTwo): void
```

So to some extent you get the desired overloading behavior as well (although there are observable differences between actually overloading a function and using unions of rest tuples).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMBnACgQwJYCcBiWD2AtgKoB2G+pAPACoB8MAvMDKzDTFAB4hSkAmSGAFdSAa1L4A7qRgB+GAG0AZtiQgEYAFwwxifMvYAaGEigBjSv0069YA+wC6MHaSgA3KFgDcwUJFgaAIB5NyYYAG8YNB11LAxSAHMTACNYkHikmABff2h2AJopfHCo83TM5Jh+CoTEnL9wfIARfABlIigQAAs6gEEsRKFGeERUTFwCEnJKWhCwgB8C6CL8Ol8AegAqGCbYVo7CLt6kgaHwljYlVSx1G119QyDoUKgTM0sBe7sHZ6hX5xLS5sFRqDSIWyPZZQVbvCxWb5Qv6rZzALYbPzKUTmEAUWT8dqdHp1AAUADoKaDbuCwHDPtZEI4dJpxtg8EQyHi5i9FtDVnQAJSRYEwT5IfAAGygZIl+ESJJud0QdIRiAFwFyfmABMOx1JAHI0PqTPqUvqBb4dUSTvL9eZjTB9fxzZbCUdiUkSYaHd6Ldq3XrPd6Tfa-cANhtqgGPfLw5Grgm2AA9GAARg2ACYo7qYwqwYj7E95m9TPCvhCHoXoa8BTp3PgMPw44mW6wM5ns9bSYqaZCq8jiiry9pK79CsVazB642gA)

Comment: thanks for sharing too. And for your clear but extensive explanation!